# Flutter: How to attach label to FABs without affecting layout?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a column of FABs and text, which is there to label the FAB (I prefer the look of this over using the label on FAB.extended, as it uses vertical space rather than horizontal)

My issue is that if the text wraps to the second line, the spacing of the buttons becomes uneven in order to make room for the extra line of text.

I can try eyeballing it by adjusting the sizedBox to compensate, but is there a cleaner way of doing it, such as making the layout of the buttons ignore the text?

```
Column(
  children: [
    drawCircleButton(),
    const Text("Circle Map"),
    const SizedBox(height:10),
    drawPolyButton(),
    const Text("Draw Map")
    const SizedBox(height:10),
    addControlPointsButton(),
    const Text("Add Control\nPoints"),
    const SizedBox(height:10),
    addFinalDestinationButton(),
    const Text("Add Ending\nZone"),
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the text in one line and show a tooltip when tapped it

Code:

```
Tooltip(
   message: 'your text',
   triggerMode: TooltipTriggerMode.tap,
   child: Text(
     'your text',
      maxLines: 1,
      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
   ),
);
```